# Using Nuxt, Google Tag Manager, and Vuex

Tags: javascript, module, vuex, google-tag-manager, nuxt.js

I'm trying to send event data to Google Tag Manger in a Nuxt project. This package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager, provides what I need. The example they give presupposes that I want to call the function from within a component:

```
this.$gtm.pushEvent({ event: 'myEvent', ...someAttributes })
```

However, I actually need to call the function from a Vuex module, in which `this` is undefined. I would think I could do it like this:

```
import GTM from '@nuxtjs/google-tag-manager';

export default {
  actions: {
    myAction(_, data) {
      GTM.pushEvent(data);
    },
  ...
```

But this results in:

```
TypeError: _nuxtjs_google_tag_manager__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.pushEvent is not a function
```

I also tried:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const vm = new Vue();

export default {
  actions: {
    myAction(_, data) {
      vm.$gtm.pushEvent(data);
    },
  ...
```

But this results in:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushEvent' of undefined
```

Interestingly, when I log `vm`, I see `$gtm: undefined` as a property. So apparently the plugin is there, but it's not activated? I know I'm missing something basic here ...

Comment: If it's made for nuxt what makes you think it will work for vuex ?

Comment: Nuxt uses Vuex.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$gtm.push({ event: 'myEvent', ...someAttributes })`

it's push not pushEvent